# C++ array with multiple object

Tags: c++, oop

This is my code for input list vehicle (can Car or Truck). But it's not work and error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Vehicle' and 'Car*'). How I can input vehicle (can Car or Truck) for true?

```cpp
class Vehicle {};
class Car : public Vehicle {};
class Truck : public Vehicle {};

class ListVehicle {
  Vehicle *pVehicle;
  int n;

 public:
  void input() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int type;
      cout << "Enter vehicle type (1: car, 2: truck): ";
      cin >> type;
      cin.ignore();
      switch (type) {
        case 1: {
          pVehicle[i] = new Car();
          break;
        }
        case 2: {
          pVehicle[i] = new Truck();
          break;
        }
        default:
          cout << "Invalid type" << endl;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but you do want to notice that you are advancing i even for an invalid entry. This is a bug. You also aren't showing the initialization of pVehicle, which if omitted or wrong could be another bug.

Comment: TLDR: use data structures from STL when possible. Here, use a `std::list` and append vehicles to its end with `push_back`.

Comment: `pVehicle[i]` has type `Vehicle`, but `new Car` has type `Vehicle *`. Of course there don't exist an `operator=` that assign `Vehicle *` to `Vehicle`.

Comment: Thanks for support, I use list and solved the problem

Comment: First problem you never allocate the storage for the `pVehicle` array. Second problem a `Vehicle` array can not hold `Car` or `Truck`, only a `Vehicle*` array can hold, in which case you should be using `std::uniqe_ptr<Vehicle>` or `std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>`. And you should be using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of a C-style array. Don't write C code disguised as C++.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround

```cpp
    list<Vehicle *> vehicles;
    case 1:
    {
        Car *car = new Car();
        car->input();
        vehicles.push_back(car);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        Truck *truck = new Truck();
        truck->input();
        vehicles.push_back(truck);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
std::array<Vehicle *, 50> pVehicle;
```

Which would ensure that `pVehicle[i]` was a pointer.

Comment: Maybe I use wrong syntax or whatever. I mean just want to create 1 array of Vehicle then call input function to input any type of vehicle (be it Car or Truck)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see more important it's that you are trying to increment the memory address of `pVehicle`, even when you didn't know exactly the size of that object. in order to fix this problem, the best you can do is use one of the standard.

If you already know how much elements will store, and also you know the number of elements will not increase, I suggest you to use the std:array, otherwise if you will increasing commonly adding elements I recommend you use the std::list (this topic it's really dense, if you need to know more look https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/?ref=leftbar-rightbar).

```
enum vehicleOpt {car, track/*,.....*/}

class Vehicle {
  pure virtual void foo();
};
class Car : public Vehicle {
   void foo() override;
};
class Truck : public Vehicle {
  void foo() override;
};

void main(){
  std::list<vehicle*> vehicles;
  //std::array<vehicle*, n> vehicles;
  //....

  switch(option){
    case enumOpt::car:
      auto vehicle = new Car();
      break;
    case enumOpt::track:
      auto vehicle = new track();
      break;
      //..... as many case you need. also throw an error if not exist.
   }

   vehicle.foo();
   vehicles.push_back(vehicle);


}
```

In this approach I also try to use the polymorphism of the vehicle object, and try to reduce the boilerplate code.